# How can I display HTML tags as Text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to display unrendered HTML code using class `html` and the below jquery code.
Its working for every tag except for tags `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`.
Is there a way these can also be displayed as text?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.html').each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).html());
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<pre>
<div class="html">
    <html>
    <head><title>Title</title></head>
    <body>
    <p>Unrendred html</p>
    </body>
    </html>
</div>
</pre>
```

Expected content:

```
<div class="html">
    <html>
    <head><title>Title</title></head>
    <body>
    <p>Unrendred html</p>
    </body>
    </html>
</div>
```

Actual content:

```
<title>Title</title>

<p>Unrendred html</p>
```

Comment: The browser is removing the invalid tags. What is the end goal here? I'm sure there is a better way to solve this problem (possibly templates?).

Comment: i wanted to make an html document which shows HTML code snippets which  includes <html>, <head> and <body> tags..

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML is invalid. You can't have most of those tags where you are putting them.

When the browser tries to parse your invalid HTML, it hits your errors and attempts to recover from them.

The result of this is that they are never put inside the `.html` element in the DOM, so when you try to convert the DOM back to HTML they won't appear.

The only way you could scrape them out of there would be to refetch the raw source code from the server and then parse the HTML yourself.

Just write the HTML correctly in the first place. If you want to render a `<` character then put `&lt;` in the HTML (and so on). Don't try to escape the HTML with JavaScript after the browser has already parsed it.

Answer (score 3):

you need to replace the tag syntax as below

expected result at this fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/uEMh2/

```
<pre>
&lt;div class="html"&gt;
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Title&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Unrendred html&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 escapeHTML {
     return html.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
 }
```

Thats the way prototype handles it.

Answer (score 1):

**i tried to solve your problem by jquery but you have to add one unused `<pre>` tag to your code and two lines of `jquery code`**

if you ignore `<pre>` and `jquery script` on output then everything is as you wan't

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var data = $('html').html();
                data = "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n"+data+"\n</html>";
                var data = $('pre#html-code').text(data);
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="html-code"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

escape the `<>` characters - on your html, and on your js as well use `html` function instead of `html()`

```
<pre>
<div class="html">
    &lt;p&gt;&lt; html / &gt;&lt;/p &gt
    &lt;head &gt;&lt;title &gt;Title&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head &gt;
    &lt;body &gt;
    &lt;p &gt;Unrendred html&lt;/p &gt;
    &lt;/body &gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
</div>
</pre>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.html').each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).html);
    });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/p3BXK/16/

Comment: he get same result as you. i think he want to see <html> and <body> elements too.

Comment: it still does not change the output. tags <html>, <head> and <body> are still missing in the output.

Comment: @webSpider yes, nice way to "cheat" browser :D

Comment: @webSpider: Now you don't need the replace function.

Comment: You don't need the JavaScript at all.